# React Native - Navigating from a React Native screen to a native Java (Android Studio) screen

Tags: java, react-native, react-navigation

I have a React Native project integrated with an Android Studio java project (meaning part of my application works with java and part with react native), and I need to be able to navigate from one of my react native screens to one of the java screens. I've got the navigation inside the react native part all covered up (I'm using the react-navigation package), but I can't get my head around navigating to a java screen.
So far, I've looked everywhere on the Internet and the package's documentation, but it seems there's simply no information about this, or maybe I missed something. Either way, can anyone point me in the right direction on how to navigate between react native and native screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React native allows communication between JAVA and JS. To achieve what you want to do you will need to call a method from JS to JAVA where you can use intents to open a new screen. It's too much to explain and I probably wouldn't do it justice but you can go through the docs.

[Native Modules Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html)

Comment: Worked like a charm, I knew I was missing something and that was using native modules. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: No problem. Also just a quick tip you can use this communication between JS and JAVA as a way to transfer information between both of them as well